# Vertex operator change from conformal normal ordering to operator normal ordering

Tags: operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

Boundary Conformal Field Theory and the Worldsheet Approach to D-Branes by Andreas Recknagel and Volker Schomerus. The "tachyon vertex operators" defined by

> $$\phi_{k,k}(z,\bar z) = :e^{ikX(z,\bar z)}:$$

where $k^2=g^{\mu_\nu} k_\mu k_\nu$, $k\diamond k=G^{ij} k_ik_j$, and $::$ was the conformal normal ordering, shown in Eq. 1.19 as

> $$T(z)=\frac{1}{\alpha'}\sum g_{\mu\nu} :J^\mu J^\nu:(z)=\frac{1}{\alpha'}\lim _{w\rightarrow z} (g_{\mu\nu}J^\mu(w)J^\nu(z)-\frac{\alpha'}{2}\frac{D}{(w-z)^2} )$$

However, in Eq. 1.27

> $$\phi_{k,k}(z,\bar z) = \frac{1}{|z-\bar z|^{\alpha' (k^2/2 -k\diamond k)}} ;e^{ikX(z,\bar z)};$$

where $;;$ was the operator normal ordering(not sure how to type the empty colons).

Also, note that

> the two-point functions(propagators) of the free boson bulk theory on the full plane was
> $$\langle X^\mu(z_1,\bar z_1) X^\nu(z_2,\bar z_2) \rangle_{bulk}=-\alpha'g^{\mu\nu}\ln |z_1-z_2|$$
> where on the upper half plane
> $$\langle X^\mu(z_1,\bar z_1) X^\nu(z_2,\bar z_2) \rangle_{bdy}=-\alpha'g^{\mu\nu}\ln |z_1-z_2| -\alpha'g^{\mu\nu}\ln |z_1-\bar z_2|-\alpha'G^{\mu\nu}\ln |z_1-\bar z_2|^2 -\Theta^{\mu\nu}\ln\frac{z_1-\bar z_2}{\bar z_1-z_2}$$

Could you show how was the vertex operator change from conformal normal ordering to operator normal ordering, please?

Comment: The vertex operator in the bulk have a divergent OPE with the boundary, so in order to define an operator *at* the boundary you need to regularize (say by taking it very close to the boundary) and renormalize (subtract the divergent part of the OPE).

Comment: @Nogueira We were working somewhat on that trend, by taking $e^{ikX(,z,\bar z)}\rightarrow e^{ikX(,z) +ik \bar X(\bar z)} $  i.e. separate the holomorphic and antiholomorphic pieces and then basically calculate the OPE of products of vertex operators, but a conversion from operator normal ordering $;$ to conformal normal ordering $:$ was still needed, and the technical details were confusing.

Comment: Probably the fastest way to see this is to calculate two-point function $\langle e^{ipX} e^{iqX} \rangle$ in the bulk (i.e. $;;$) and upper half plane (i.e. $::$) and compare. To be sure you would need to calculate higher-point functions, too.